# VisualSVN Server is not installed on local computer

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN server installed on my Windows Vista system. It used to work fine before but now when I try to open the VisualSVN Server Manager I get the following error.

```
VisualSVN Server is not installed on local computer
```

However, I can do everything using TortoiseSVN client and view the source from web browser.
On further investigation I found that it is looking for Apache 2.2 and I have Apache 2.0 installed. It could be that some libraries were updated. But why is it looking for Apache 2.2 when it was never there?

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\VisualSVNServer
.exe" -k runservice -C "LoadModule log_visualsvn_module bin/mod_log_visualsvn.so
" -E nul
(OS 1063)The service process could not connect to the service controller.  : Err
or starting service control dispatcher
[Wed Apr 09 10:04:43 2014] [error] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specifi
ed.  : No installed service named "Apache2.2".
```

Comment: 1. VisualSVN Server includes highly-isolated Apache HTTP Server 2.2 instance. 2. You encountered an outstanding issue, contact support@visualsvn.com for investigation, please.

Comment: Don't really know what went wrong. Didn't have time for investigation so just updated the VisualSVN server with the latest version and it seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: If you encounter the issue again, please contact us at support@visualsvn.com or via the contact form at http://www.visualsvn.com/support/feedback/?vsvn-server=

Answer (score 0):

This problem has to be caused by insufficient service permissions. You need to read the article [KB37: Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/) and fix the permissions.